# How does calling JavaScript functions work?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm a student and I'm coming from a lower level language (Java), so I'm very confused about this.

For example:

```
function sum (x){
let z = function (y) {return x + y };
return z;
}
sum(1)(2) // returns 3
```

How does `sum(1)(2)` work? I think`sum(1)` returns `z`, upon which `z(2)` is called but I don't quite understand this. Also, why can you just initialize`z` as `function (y)` without giving that function a name? Any tips on approaching JavaScript from a lower-level language perspective?
I'm having a hard time.

Comment: you really consider Javascript as a higher level language than Java ?

Comment: @Marged well I just interpret higher level with having less things to explicitly define/more automaticity..  so I guess so? Probably a wrong definition though so that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

#### How does sum(1)(2) work?

You are calling `sum(1)` and than you call the return value with `(2)`. In this case, the return value is a function, so you can call it. It's the same as writing it like this:

```js
function sum(x) {
  let z = function(y) {
    return x + y
  };
  return z;
}
let returnValue = sum(1);
console.log(returnValue);
console.log(returnValue(2));
```

As you can see, `returnValue` is a function, like expected. This function takes 1 argument, `y`, and use the `x` from the first function's creation scope to return `x + y`.

#### Why can you define z as function without a name?

When you are using the syntax `let z = something` you are using an expression to define the `something`. Just like you will define `let a = 1` and not `let a = myVar 1` (??), the same with functions. You don't need to give it a name because you can refer to the function as `z`. Got it?

#### Any tips on approaching JavaScript

If you wanna learn JS, I really recommend you to read [You Don't Know Javascript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS). Iv'e read it after I thought I know JS, and Iv'e discovered a lot of things that I didn't knew about.
It also explains how things works in js.

More over there are a lot of websites that can teach and train you. Just google it.

#### IMPORTANT NOTE

`java` is not a low level language but a high level one.

Comment: Hey Omri, thanks for your answer. I didn't actually say Java was a low level language, but just as in, lower than JS (same for C++, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You're right that `sum(1)` returns z, which is just a variable that is assigned an anonymous function.

In JS, functions can be defined in two ways, as a function declaration or a function expression. You can look up MDN for the exact definitions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

What you have there is a function expression and function expressions can be named or anonymous.

I would also suggest reading more about how functions in JS maintain their own scope, which is how `z` has a reference to the argument `x`.

I hope this gives you more insight!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are objects( in fact everything is an object ), hence they can be referenced using variables or returned from other functions. So when you do return z from your function it returns an anonymous function.

Go through the below links to know about functions in JavaScript.

https://javascript.info/object-methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Hope it helps.